# Общий ли член предложения в ССП? Какое правило препятствует постановке запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, ссп

> *Атрий* – так назывался этот центральный зал, в котором протекала
>   жизнь. Здесь собиралась семья для трапезы или отдыха, здесь
>   приносились жертвы домашним богам – *ларам*, здесь располагался и
>   кабинет хозяйки и никто не мог прошмыгнуть мимо неё, не обратив на
>   себя внимания.

"И никто не мог прошмыгнуть" подпадает под обаяние "здесь" или уже таки живёт своей жизнью? О_о

Comment: Живёт своей жизнью!

Comment: Атрий (лат. atrium) — центральная часть древнеримского и древнеиталийского жилища, представлявшая собой внутренний световой двор. Лучше и привычнее — внутренний двор и атриум.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Здесь собиралась семья для трапезы или отдыха, здесь приносились жертвы домашним богам – ларам, здесь располагался и кабинет хозяйки, и никто не мог прошмыгнуть мимо неё, не обратив на себя внимания.*

Думаю, что запятая нужна, потому что "здесь" относится к тем фактам, которые доказывают, что это **центральный** зал, важный для жизни семьи, а последнее предложение присоединяется к предыдущему, связано  по смыслу только с ним.